# vba using R1C1 sum formula referring to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem including reference to another worksheet in a R1C1 SUM formula, using Excel 2010.

this works

```
Range("B39").FormulaR1C1 = "='Fello VIP P-L'!R[49]C"
```

and this works

```
Range("B40").FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R[36]C:R[38]C)"
```

but this gives an error

```
Range("B40").FormulaR1C1 = "='Fello VIP P-L'!sum(R[36]C:R[38]C)"
```

help and education would be very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first specify the function, here it's `Sum`, and inside the brackets, where you specify which `Range` to sum, you specify the worksheet's name, and afterwards the cells (R1C1).

```
Range("B40").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM('Fello VIP P-L'!R[36]C:R[38]C)"
```